# No more internet connection after update in 14.04 with Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 7260

Tags: wireless, networking

My Dell XPS 15 (haswell) was working fine until a recent update. Since then, my wifi does not work (it shows "device not managed" when clicking wifi icon in toolbar). Even USB to Ethernet adapter does not seem to work. Bluetooth at least "sees" other bluetooth devices around...

Output of `dmesg (dmesg |grep iwl)` :

```
[  886.462459] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: irq 51 for MSI/MSI-X
[  886.462561] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[  886.462562] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[  886.463284] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.1.7.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[  886.475345] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[  886.475433] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[  886.475684] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[  886.689214] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
```

And from `modinfo iwlwifi`:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-29-       generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
srcversion:     1E6912E109D5A43B310FB34
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005490bc*sc*i*

(a pack of lines of kind "alias:  pci:xxxxx...." that I guess are not helpful)

alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005290bc*sc*i*
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        66:02:CB:36:F1:31:3B:EA:01:C4:BD:A9:65:67:CF:A7:23:C9:70:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off     (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
```

I downloaded the latest versions of `iwlwifi` firmware:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

copied `iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode  iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode  iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode` to `/lib/firmware` and rebooted

But as you can imagine it did not help.

Update #1:

Downloaded from http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.15.8.0.tgz

and copied the file into `/lib/firmware`.

After reloading it with modprobe, it seems to be OK:

```
[   14.761283] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   14.761472] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: irq 51 for MSI/MSI-X
[   14.772478] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.15.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   14.800274] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[   14.800349] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   14.800657] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   15.007048] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
```

However, clicking in wifi in the toolbar still shows "device not managed".

Any clues?

Comment: I suggest you also try this firmware: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.15.8.0.tgz  Let me know if you need explicit instructions.

Comment: Thanks chili555. See my update: the firmware now seems to be loaded but still no wifi available...

Comment: looking at http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7560830.html, can I suspect of network-manager? `nmcli -v tool nmcli, version 0.9.8.8`

Comment: What does this tell us? cat /etc/network/interfaces  If there are entries for wlan0, please remove and reboot.

Comment: Thank you again! Just read your comment just after writing the answer

Comment: Glad it's working.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1923375) and [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1923375) on Ubuntu Forums, I found the solution to my problem:

I changed the last parameter in this section of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` from `false` to `true`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=**true**
```

And removed this entire section fron `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface br0 inet dhcp
   bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
   bridge_stp on
   bridge_fd 0
```

I am not sure how those parameters got messed up - perhaps because I was playing with KVM network parameters, trying to create a bridge connection.

Anyway, problem solved.