# Intel AC 7620 No Internet, Still Connected to Network

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, kernel

I bought a new Asus n550jv laptop which has a Intel AC 7620 wireless card inside of it. I installed Arch Linux on it and noticed that I will be connected to my corporate wifi and every once and a while I will just lose all internet connectivity, but my wifi connection says it's fine. After enough times of connecting and restarting, sometimes it seems to work. I got it to randomly yesterday for almost 4 hours. I tried going to linux-wireless and downloading the newest iwlwifi driver I can use, version 22.24.8.0. Didn't seem to help. Also tired the solution in [No more internet connection after update in 14.04 with Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 7260](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480583/no-more-internet-connection-after-update-in-14-04-with-intel-dual-band-wireless) and that didn't work as well. I have tried using different distros in some vain attempt to fix this: Arch Linux, Linux Mint 17, Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 12.10, and a new other Ubuntu variants.

The module parameters right now

```
sudo grep -H '' /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/*

/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/11n_disable:0
/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/amsdu_size_8K:0
/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/antenna_coupling:0
/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/bt_coex_active:Y
/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/fw_restart:Y
/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/led_mode:0
/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/nvm_file:(null)
/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/power_level:0
/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/power_save:N
/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/swcrypto:0
/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/wd_disable:1
```

The module info

```
modinfo iwlwifi

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
srcversion:     1E6912E109D5A43B310FB34
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005490bc*sc*i*
... a ton of aliases here
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        69:B0:D0:A7:9B:85:D9:06:21:70:6E:8D:06:60:4D:73:0B:35:9F:C0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
```

The dmesg for iwlwifi

```
dmesg | grep iwlwifi

[   23.538445] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: irq 54 for MSI/MSI-X
[   23.763701] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.24.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   23.773794] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[   23.773849] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   23.774078] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   29.060120] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   29.060349] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   33.188933] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: No association and the time event is over already...
[ 1364.975013] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1366.269647] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[ 1366.270713] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[ 1366.270957] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[ 1579.332242] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1582.073419] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[ 1582.075299] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[ 1582.075551] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
```

Has anyone else had this problem? I have been trying to fix this for almost 2 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it didn't perfectly fix everything. But adding

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0
```

to a /etc/modprobe.d file (you can name it whatever) even though I thought I tried this once already.